# RDP without host machine unlocking

Tags: 17.10, remote-desktop, remote-access, rdp

I would like to remotely connect to my Ubuntu from another Ubuntu machine.

The problem is when I'm at the remote location and I log in via RDP, it also unlocks my host PC. I would like to log in as the same user but in a different session so that my host PC doesn't get controlled.

Is this possible?

I have looked into vncserver / noMachine / xrdp without a solution.